# Error when trying to start a Catalyst server

Tags: perl, catalyst

Running the Catalyst internal server, located at `scripts/MyApp_server.pm`, I receive the following error. Is there any one who can help me in this regard? 
I have not changed any of the files created by catalyst.pl. I just have run the catalyst.pl MyApp and then run scripts/MyApp_server.pl -r for testing whether Catalyst works or not. This is the only things I have done!
I have reinstalled Catalyst and its dependent modules several times by using either yum and cpan. But it doesn't work again.

Thanks!

**THE ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst.pm line 2681.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Ali/Lab/WEB/catalyst/MyApp3/script/../lib/MyApp3.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 50
```

**The codes around line 2681 in /usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst.pm are as below:**

```
    sub setup_home {

        my ( $class, $home ) = @_;

        if ( my $env = Catalyst::Utils::env_value( $class, 'HOME' ) ) {
            $home = $env;
        }

        $home ||= Catalyst::Utils::home($class);
        if ($home) {
            #I remember recently being scolded for assigning config values like this
            $class->config->{home} ||= $home; # THIS IS LINE 2681
            $class->config->{root} ||= Path::Class::Dir->new($home)->subdir('root');
        }
    }
```

**The content of the lib/MyApp.pm is as below:**

```
package MyApp;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

use Catalyst::Runtime 5.80;

# Set flags and add plugins for the application
#
#         -Debug: activates the debug mode for very useful log messages
#   ConfigLoader: will load the configuration from a Config::General file in the
#                 application's home directory
# Static::Simple: will serve static files from the application's root
#                 directory

use Catalyst qw/
    -Debug
    ConfigLoader
    Static::Simple
/;

extends 'Catalyst';

our $VERSION = '0.01';
$VERSION = eval $VERSION;

# Configure the application.
#
# Note that settings in myapp.conf (or other external
# configuration file that you set up manually) take precedence
# over this when using ConfigLoader. Thus configuration
# details given here can function as a default configuration,
# with an external configuration file acting as an override for
# local deployment.

__PACKAGE__->config(
    name => 'MyApp',
    # Disable deprecated behavior needed by old applications
    disable_component_resolution_regex_fallback => 1,
);

# Start the application
__PACKAGE__->setup();


=head1 NAME

MyApp - Catalyst based application

=head1 SYNOPSIS

    script/myapp_server.pl

=head1 DESCRIPTION

[enter your description here]

=head1 SEE ALSO

L<MyApp::Controller::Root>, L<Catalyst>

=head1 AUTHOR

Ali Basirat

=head1 LICENSE

This library is free software. You can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the same terms as Perl itself.

=cut

1;
```

Comment: You'll probably need to post the few lines of code around line 2681 in Catalyst.pm so someone familiar with it can make a suggestion. Try lines from 2670 to 2690, and perhaps the name of the sub.

Comment: The lines of code around line 2681 are as below:        sub setup_home {
    my ( $class, $home ) = @_;

    if ( my $env = Catalyst::Utils::env_value( $class, 'HOME' ) ) {
        $home = $env;
    }

    $home ||= Catalyst::Utils::home($class);

    if ($home) {
        #I remember recently being scolded for assigning config values like this
        ===== THIS IS LINE 2681 ==== $class->config->{home} ||= $home;
        $class->config->{root} ||= Path::Class::Dir->new($home)->subdir('root');
    }
}

Comment: Guess we'll be able to find the Catalyst sources online. However, since the framework usually works, I bet that MyApp.pm is doing something nasty. Also: there usually is no `scripts/MyApp_server.pm` file.

Comment: @Ali Basirat: Please add any code to your question and don't try to put it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the code. My guess is that `lib/MyApp.pm` is somehow broken.

Comment: Some details of the code is added.

Comment: Show your application code, not the Catalyst core code.

Comment: The content of the lib/MyApp.pm is also added. I have not changed any of the files created by catalyst.pl. I just have run the catalyst.pl MyApp and then run scripts/MyApp_server.pl -r for testing whether Catalyst works or not. This is the only things I have done!

Comment: you could have mentioned that a wee bit earlier.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a definitive answer, but hopefully will help a little.

You've either got an undefined `$class` or `$class->config` (more likely), although how I can't say. Perhaps the ConfigLoader hasn't worked.

Re-installing things blindly seldom helps and the problem could be due to any module in the dependency list. If there was a specific problem installing a module then there would have been an error and we could have worked on that.

So - using yum install [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/release/App-cpanminus) and [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) - I'm not sure what the packages are called on Red Hat, but it should be easy enough to find out.

OK - now create a new directory somewhere suitable.

```
mkdir /home/Devt/catalyst_test
cd /home/Devt/catalyst_test
eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib=./perllib)
echo $PERL5LIB
# You should see your current directory mentioned in PERL5LIB
cpanm Catalyst
cpanm Catalyst::Helper
catalyst.pl MyApp
cd MyApp/
perl Makefile.PL
./script/myapp_server.pl
# Opens up a server on port 3000
```

What local::lib is doing is setting up the paths to install everything locally (in perllib) - you can see the environment variables it sets up by running it without the eval.

```
perl -Mlocal::lib=./perllib
```

See the docs for how to add it to a bash login script. I just redirect the output to a file and source it when I'm working on a project (I use one perllib per project).

Then, cpanm is smart enough to use this local directory to install all the bits you need.

If this doesn't work, the problem is probably due to something you've manually installed in /usr/local/. *Take a backup* of the various perl-related lib dirs in /usr/local/ and then clean them out. Run cpanm again (checking local::lib paths are setup first) and see if the versions it downloads work.

The above should work - it's exactly what I did 10 minutes ago.

The whole idea of this is to create a separate installation of all your perl libraries for this project - that way if you upgrade anything it only affects the current installation.